# jQuery Select multiple div elements by ID using startswith common string

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to set the same css for all of these div elements:

```
    <div id="Some_id_1"></div>
    <div id="Some_id_2"></div>
    <div id="Some_id_3"></div>
```

How can I do that?
thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use the jQuery [Attribute Starts With Selector:](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

**Usage:**

```
$('[attribute^="value"]')
```

**Example, fitting your needs:**

```
$('div[id^="Some_id_"]').each(function(){
    $(this).css('property','value');
});
```

This would be useful for setting these properties dynamically, however if you are just setting them in a static sense, I would recommend just applying a `class="your_class"` to all of your divs.

**A Working Demo can be found here :**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GkqNY/)

Answer (score 0):

Make them all members of a class, then use a class selector.

```
<div class="some_class" id="Some_id_1"></div>
<div class="some_class" id="Some_id_2"></div>
<div class="some_class" id="Some_id_3"></div>

.some_class {
    line-height: 1.1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, give your `div` a class:

```
<div id="Some_id_1" class="newClass"></div>
<div id="Some_id_2" class="newClass"></div>
<div id="Some_id_3" class="newClass"></div>
```

and then select the class and modify the css using [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$(".newClass").css("color","red");
```

...

Not knowing your code, I'll also throw out [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) which suits some applications better.

```
$("div").addClass("newClass");
```

The above example will add a class to ANY `div`, so you'll have to play with the selector that makes sense for your project, and then just have some existing css:

```
.newClass { color: red }
```

Comment: Thanks, I am having problems with code that is generated on server and then rendered as html. It has some pattern of giving ids to element, I would rather avoid changing server code in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

To use the same style to all elements with the same id put it this

```
.yourClass {
  line-height: 1.1;
}

$('[id^="Some_id_"]').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("yourClass");
});
```